# ошибка трансляции xfce4

Tags: termux, xfce4

пытаюсь запустить xfce4 в термуксе через proot-distro archlinux, так же происходит в других дистриубиивах proot(Ubuntu, Debian).

 [скрин](https://longestsoloever.ru/Screenshot_2023-11-09-02-30-04-100_com.termux.png)

ошибка:

~ $ proot-distro login archlinux --user user --shared-tmp -- bash -c "export DISPLAY=:0 PULSE_SERVER=tcp:127.0.0.1; dbus-launch --exit-with-session xfce4-session --display=:0"

(process:23927): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:22:03.083: Locale not supported by C library.
Using the fallback 'C' locale.
_IceTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.ICE-unix should be set to root

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.697: Failed to spawn ssh-agent: Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.700: failed to call dbus-update-activation-environment. Output was (null), error was Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.708: Failed to spawn gpg-agent: Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.721: Unable to launch "xfwm4": Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.724: Unable to launch "xfsettingsd": Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.729: Unable to launch "xfce4-panel": Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.731: Unable to launch "Thunar": Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.734: Unable to launch "xfdesktop": Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.743: Unable to launch "sh -c "systemctl --user start xfce4-notifyd.service 2>/dev/null || exec /usr/lib/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd"" (specified by autostart/xfce4-notifyd.desktop): Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.747: Unable to launch "xfce4-power-manager" (specified by autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop): Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.752: Unable to launch "/usr/lib/polkit-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1" (specified by autostart/xfce-polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop): Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

(xfce4-session:23927): xfce4-session-WARNING **: 23:22:03.760: Unable to launch "xfsettingsd" (specified by autostart/xfsettingsd.desktop): Failed to close file descriptor for child process (Invalid argument)

[и: udroid jammy:xfce](https://longestsoloever.ru/IMG_20231110_181411.jpg)